# MySqlDataReader must be closed

Tags: c#, mysql

```
MySqlCommand status =
    new MySqlCommand("select name_ru from request_status where id = '50'", conn);
MySqlDataReader dr_status = status.ExecuteReader();
dr_status.Read();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

error:

> MySqlDataReader must be closed first

Please, help...

Comment: Why are you calling ExecuteReader so many times? You must close an open reader before you use another.

Comment: Why do you want to Execute the reader twice?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use only one reader at the same time. You are using three. Wrap all readers in a using-block to ensure that they get disposed in all cases.

`ExecuteReader` is what executes your SQL. In your sample code you execute the same SQL three times which might not be what you intended.